# "Couldn't find any package" - Error with Boost on Ubuntu

Tags: apt, boost

### Problem

I have tried to install Boost version 1.55 (I require this specific version for my programs) using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost1.55-all-dev
```

But it keeps giving me the error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree Reading state
information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libboost1.55-all-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libboost1.55-all-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libboost1.55-all-dev'
```

---

### What I have tried

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/806478/xenial-16-04-cannot-find-package-libboost-all-dev) suggests to try:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

But, I continue to get the same error.

---

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/784868/ubuntu-doesnt-recognize-specific-package-through-apt-get) suggests to try:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager    
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

But, that only gave me the following errors, which I could not find a way around:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 y-ppa-manager : Depends: yad (>= 0.36.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335372/couldnt-find-any-package-by-regex-libstdc-so-5-libexpat-so-0-in-32-bit-ubuntu) suggests to try using apt-file to search for the packages that I require to install it, but nothing shows up when I run the search command.

---

### Question

What are the possible causes & solutions of this issue?

Comment: The real problem may be this: "I require this specific version for my programs".  If you have full control of your (C++) programs, you could build all of them with `g++ -static` or `clang -static` on the older system. Statically linked executables are self-contained, so they keep working without issues even when you upgrade your OS / env.  Moreover, you could even copy them to a non Ubuntu system (as long as it is Linux with the same architecture) and have them work too.

Comment: I don't really have full control over my programs, since they are pre-built SDK's form another source. So, that's not really a possibility.

Answer (score 3):

**The cause of your problem** is the assumption that the Ubuntu repositories are comprehensive and keeps older software.

In fact, Ubuntu is a 'snapshot' distro. During the release process, only the latest stable snapshot of all available software is included. Older versions are not included.

**Possible Solutions**

1) If the source is available, you can recompile against the current dependencies.

2) Libboost1.55 is available in some older versions of Ubuntu.

```
$ rmadison libboost1.55-dev
libboost1.55-dev | 1.55.0-1             | trusty/universe | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
libboost1.55-dev | 1.55.0+dfsg-3ubuntu2 | vivid           | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
```

Your **safest, simplest solution** is to install Ubuntu 14.04 into a VM to run your software safely without breaking your current system.

Some might suggest **an alternative**: Downgrading libboost (installing a 14.04 package on a 16.04 system). However, this can be difficult and dangerous for not-advanced users. I have 12 years of experience tinkering with packages and the package manager, and I would not do it.

**Returning your system to a working state**

Uninstall those packages that you installed during your unsuccessful attempts. Delete those sources. Your attempts have introduced a *version conflict* (which is what 'held broken packages' means). Your package manager is broken. You cannot install, uninstall, nor update your system (including security updates) until you fix it.